# How enable full screen notifications with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-push-notification, react-native-push-notification

How to enable full screen notifications using React Native (android only).

I'm using [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) and this works fine but it's not full screen.

I found [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-native-full-screen-notification-tricking-android-1761e4fd2ac3), it describes how to add this functionality for notifications from firebase but I need to do it for local notifications.

I tried to do it with [those steps](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1482) but it looks like it doesn't works with current versions.

I would be grateful if you could help

Comment: Did you find an answer? I've been stuck on this for a month now haha ;_;

Comment: Unfortunately not. It would be great if someone has a solution for the current / future version

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still haven't the problem and I have chosen to give normal notification.